# Duplicate questions are (incorrectly?) shown in new nav views

Tags: bug, status-completed, duplicate-questions, new-nav

I'm using the new navigation and I'm looking at this view (this *is* new, right? :) )

https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=needanswer&show=noanswer&sort=votes&page=1&pageSize=30

It should show questions that have no answer, sorted by votes (descending). My guess is that the reason to have this view, is to find (good) questions that are in need of an answer. At least that's what I've been using these new views for. :)

However, all those top questions are duplicates that once had many upvotes and probably many answers too, but were closed as duplicate and merged with another question (so their answers are gone).

This applies to the "No answer" filter. When you select "Needs answer", duplicates are not visible.

So I guess this is a bug. Duplicates should not be visible in this list, or should they?

Comment: I myself have been experiencing another bug (probably related to a new option), and posted on meta also, if you haven't seen it yet http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295649/

Comment: Related http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256943/new-navigation-page-should-hide-closed-duplicated-on-hold-questions-at-the-need and the linked dup is marked status-completed